# How to use CSS3 background linear-gradients for labels (Highcharts)

Tags: css, background, highcharts, linear-gradients

I'm trying to style a Highcharts chart like eg. [this one](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/).

What I'm searching for is a solution to add CSS3 background linear-gradients to the xAxis and yAxis labels.

Anybody who has already got something like this up and running? Or isn't it possible for the SVG charts?

THX.

Answer (score 0):

You can set useHTML as true for labels, then use formatter to define your own div and use css3 styles like in the example below:

```
labels: {
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function () {
                return '<div class="label">' + this.value + ' </div>';
            }
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MV4pb/

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.labels.formatter
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.labels.useHTML